# show a modal on a different file after completing registration on another file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a registration button when I click on it to submit and if registration is successful, will redirect to another page and THEN show the modal I have what code should I have to achieve this?

REGISTRATION:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER">
```

MODAL: (again this is the HTML file that registration redirects to if successful and submitted)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Welcome, New White Card Holder!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h3>Congratulations! you are entitled for a 30-day free trial of our <img src="../img/ribbon-elite.png" class="small-icon"> Elite Membership.</h3>
      <h3>You may begin browsing our cards right away as soon as you close this window</h3>
      <h3>Also, if you wish to avail of our other membership options, <a href="membership.php">click here.</a></h3>
      <h3>Enjoy a wealth of deals for wellness!</h3>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this javascript the triggers the modal but id like to know how to do this when the registration is submitted.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I think I can't exactly place the modal in the registration file since it just redirects to another page.

will appreciate any coded help given thank you

UPDATE: heres what i tried based on the example provided

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register']) && $_POST['register'] == 'REGISTER') {
  ?>
  <script>
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  </script>
 <?php
  }
?>
```

my if condition "if(isset($_POST['register']) && $_POST['register'] == 'REGISTER')" is the same line that works when a registration is valid. i assumed it will do the same with ".modal('show')" but the modal does not show up.

PS. i added that if condition on the page that gets redirected after registration is successful.

Comment: If you want to show the modal on this other page, then it should be part of this other page to begin with, yes. If you want to show it every time that other page is called, you could simply make it show using a load event handler. If you only want to show it if the registration was successful, then you need to make the output of the JS code that would show it on load dependent on some conditions on the server side …

Comment: Did you look at the console..Is there any error showing up like jquery is not defined..? If so try including jquery before using the above script..

Answer (score 1):

Does registration redirect to some general page that could be opened with or without modal?

If so you could use GET parameter. 
For example some-page?showModal=true

Then based on value of that parameter you could decide whether show or not modal onLoad of given page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a session active after successful form submit and show the modal if that session is active. Refer following code:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
   //Your code goes here
   ......

   $_SESSION["msg_succ"]=true;
}

if(isset($_SESSION["msg_succ"])){
  ?>
  <script>
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  </script>
 <?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: i updated my question with content regarding me testing the code you provided.